# A decent screencast software for linux?

Tags: vim, screencasts

I am looking for a screencast software for linux, i currently have kazam screencaster but it is missing out on capturing keystrokes commands, what i would like todo is make a vim screencast for friends and actually show them the vim commands i am typing in..

Comment: wrong place, man... superuser/linux&unix....

Comment: oops sorry, you are 100% right, btw i found ScreenKey, which can do this, and kazam can capture it, incase anyone will come here wondering :) cheers

Comment: screenkey, keymon both can do.

Comment: My [Replay](https://github.com/chrisbra/Replay) vim plugin can be used to created Recordings of Vim sessions.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: You should make it a true answer instead of comment